# JSF: Avoid parent page bean re-initialization when dialog is launched?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using Prime Faces (JSF UI library).

I have a page with several `commandLink` buttons that each brings up a dialog.

```
<f:view>
<h:form>
.
.
.
    <p:dataTable value="#{ServerMgmtBean.objectList}" var="server">
.
.
.
    <p:commandLink oncomplete="dlgAssignServers.show()">        
        <p:graphicImage alt="Assign Image" value="./images/assign.png" />
    </p:commandLink>
.
.
.
</h:form>

<p:dialog id="assignServersDialog" header="Assign Servers" widgetVar="dlgAssignServers" modal="true" width="400">
    <ui:include src="assign/assign_sg_servers.xhtml"/>
</p:dialog>

</f:view>
```

The problem is that each time I click on the `commmandLink`, all the beans behind the page get re-created (in this example `ServerMgmtBean`), and then the dialog is launched. All beans are request scoped.

It slows things down significantly, to the point that I need a progress indicator before the dialog appears. Why do the beans get initialized? Can I avoid this somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you are using `@RequestScoped` beans. They are recreated in every request (even in AJAX request as in your case `commandLink` will send AJAX request). Change scope to `@ViewScoped` and your page will be served with one bean per page, not per request.

Comment: Can't use view scoped beans because it requires all beans to be serialized, which is not possible in my code. Really no way out?

Comment: What is a problem to your bean implements `Serializable`? Why your beans can't be serialized?

Comment: Because all sub classes also have to be serialized, and members also, etc. I end up with everything being serialized. And all this communicates with web service which also needs to be serialized in that case. It is just overwhealming, I am not sure if at all possible to serialize all that?

Comment: Well, on those you don't want to be serialized, or it can't add `transient` modifier. That tells Java to exclude those fields from serialization.